# Forward to JSp file in liferay processAction method

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have a login page. When the user enters valid Username and Password another page should be displayed. I check the username and password in processAction method. How can I forward to another jsp from processAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use like this..

```
String myjsp;
public void init() {
        editJSP = getInitParameter("edit-jsp");
        helpJSP = getInitParameter("help-jsp");
        viewJSP = getInitParameter("view-jsp");
        //write your jsp page name 
        myjsp = getInitParameter("myjsp-jsp");

    }
```

//method to call jsp

```
protected void include(
            String path, RenderRequest renderRequest,
            RenderResponse renderResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

        PortletRequestDispatcher portletRequestDispatcher =
            getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path);

        if (portletRequestDispatcher == null) {
            _log.error(path + " is not a valid include");
        }
        else {
            portletRequestDispatcher.include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
        }
    }
```

//write this method call into action method

```
include(myjsp, request, response);
```

you can call using this method also....

```
 response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/admin/search.jsp");
```

this is easy and simplest method........

Comment: this code worked for me "response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/admin/search.jsp");" thanks